# Как получить значение из соответствующей textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

Методом `forEach` я перебираю массив картинок и к каждой картинке добавляю `div` с `textarea` для комментариев и кнопкой добавить, код приблизительно такой:

```
<div> 
   <img src="URL">
   <h1 class="h">add here..</h1>
   <textarea class='text' name=''cols='50'></textarea>
   <button class='add'>Add</button>
</div>
```

Мне нужно по клику именно на кнопку что под `textarea` вытянуть значение именно этой `textarea`. Я пробовал так:

```
$('.add').click(function() {
   var a = $(".text").val()
   $(".h").append("<br>" + a)
});
```

Но оно добавляет любой кнопкой во все дивы. Может, как-то через `this` записать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Брать текст нужно из `<textarea>`, находящейся в том же блоке что и кнопка. И, аналогично, вставлять текст нужно только в один `<h1>`:

```js
$(".add").on("click", function() {
  var text = $(this).siblings(".text").val();
  $(this).siblings(".h").append("<br/>" + text);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="h">add here..</h1>
  <textarea class='text' name='' cols='50'></textarea>
  <button class='add'>Add</button>
</div>
<div>
  <h1 class="h">add here..</h1>
  <textarea class='text' name='' cols='50'></textarea>
  <button class='add'>Add</button>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Можно немного заморочиться за оптимизацию, но это уже на любителя:

```
$(".add").on("click", function() {
    var $siblings = $(this).siblings();
    var text = $siblings.filter(".text").val();
    $siblings.filter(".h").append("<br/>" + text);
});
```

---

Если надеяться на то, что `textarea`, `h1` и `button` находятся на одном уровне, особо не приходится (а зачастую надеяться и не стоит), можно отталкиваться от целого блока с помощью связки `parents` и `find`:

```js
$(".add").on("click", function() {
  var $block = $(this).parents(".block");
  var text = $block.find(".text").val();
  $block.find(".h").append("<br/>" + text);
});
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div>
    <h1 class="h">add here..</h1>
    <textarea class='text' name='' cols='50'></textarea>
  </div>
  <button class='add'>Add</button>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div>
    <h1 class="h">add here..</h1>
    <textarea class='text' name='' cols='50'></textarea>
  </div>
  <button class='add'>Add</button>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: не работает(( вот ссылка на весь код https://codepen.io/xlabuchik/pen/WZdJow?editors=1111

Comment: вы сами можете там поставить ваш вариант

Comment: извините! я вижу ваш пример работает но можете глянуть еще раз код я вставил ваш пример но $(this).siblings(".text").val() у меня почемуто андефаинд получается

Comment: @xlabuchik у вас в вопросе `textarea` и `button` находятся на одном уровне (поэтому вариант в моём ответе работает), а в полном примере не на одном уровне (`textarea` находится внутри `form`). Либо уберите `form`, либо используйте что-то в стиле [такого варианта](https://jsfiddle.net/ghhb98k9/).

Comment: огромнейшее  спасибо!!!!

Comment: @xlabuchik на здоровье. Добавил в конец ответа полный пример работы через родителя. Если будете его полностью использовать, не забудьте про класс родителя.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.add').click(function() {
   var a= $(this).prev('.text');
   a.prev().append("<br>" + a.val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> 
   <img src="URL">
   <h1 class="h">add here..</h1>
   <textarea class='text' name=''cols='50'></textarea>
   <button class='add'>Add</button>
</div>
<div> 
   <img src="URL">
   <h1 class="h">add here..</h1>
   <textarea class='text' name=''cols='50'></textarea>
   <button class='add'>Add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Верстку в сниппет стоило добавить. Смысл оформлять код сниппетом, если он не рабочий?

Answer (score 1):

Для этого вам нужно будет добавить атрибут `id`, состоящий из префикса и номера, элементам `textarea` и `h1`. Далее к элементу `button` добавляете атрибут `data` со значением ключа этих элементов (то что после префикса):

```js
$('.add').click(function() {
  var k = $(this).data('key'),
    t = $('#t-' + k),
    h = $('#h-' + k);

  h.append("<br>" + t.val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="URL">
  <h1 class="h" id="h-12">add here..</h1>
  <textarea class="text" name="" cols="50" id="t-12"></textarea>
  <button class="add" data-key="12">Add</button>
</div>
```

Таким образом, вам не нужно будет заботиться о структуре/положении элементов